# Mouse Over an Image and Change Another

Tags: html, hover, adobe, flash-cc

This is more difficult that it needs to be to explain...

Essentially, I'm trying to make a mildly interactive website menu system in which hovering over a picture changes another picture, in HTML5.  [I perfected this with ActionScript 3 in Flash CC, so you can see what I'm trying to accomplish here.](http://kleinco.org)
Attempting to convert the ActionScript canvas to HTML5 results in a loss of the actions I applied.  I'm sure this is a fairly simple operation, building off of a simple 'change image from mouseover', as would be seen with a button or similar element.  Here is the code I used in ActionScript:

```
img1.visible=false;
img2.visible=false;
img3.visible=false;
img4.visible=false;

mClip1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, mOver2);
mClip1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT, mOut2);
mClip2.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, mOver);
mClip2.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT, mOut);
mClip3.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, mOver3);
mClip3.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT, mOut3);
mClip4.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, mOver4);
mClip4.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT, mOut4);

stop();
function mOver(e:MouseEvent):void {
    img1.visible=true;
}

function mOut(e:MouseEvent):void {
    img1.visible=false;
    gotoAndStop(5);
}
function mOver2(e:MouseEvent):void {
    img2.visible=true;
}

function mOut2(e:MouseEvent):void {
    img2.visible=false;
    gotoAndStop(10);
}
function mOver3(e:MouseEvent):void {
    img3.visible=true;
}

function mOut3(e:MouseEvent):void {
    img3.visible=false;
    gotoAndStop(15);
}
function mOver4(e:MouseEvent):void {
    img4.visible=true;
}

function mOut4(e:MouseEvent):void {
    img4.visible=false;
    gotoAndStop(20);
}
```

I have four images in the menu to be displayed, and four that would be hovered over.

This would be the code for simply **one** selection:

```
img1.visible=false;

mClip.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, mOver);
mClip.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT, mOut);

function mOver(e:MouseEvent):void {
    img1.visible=true;
}

function mOut(e:MouseEvent):void {
    img1.visible=false;
}
```

Additionally, I would like to add the ability to have hyperlinks for each of the selections (as it *is* a menu).  Thanks!

Comment: If you just change the "src" attribute of the image (with JS), this would remove the trouble of setting visibility of two different images. And if you use JQuery, changing the attributes and adding listeners would be MUCH easier.

Comment: And do you mean you want to do this in *Javascript*, not HTML5? JavaScript is the scripting portion...

Comment: Does my answer help? If it does, please accept it. If it doesn't why not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you have the image to change as `tv.jpg`, the images to hover over as `work.jpg`, `team.jpg`, and `contact.jpg`, and the altered-tv images to show when one of those three images are hovered over: `tvWork.jpg`, `tvTeam.jpg`, `tvContact.jpg`:

HTML code:

```
<img src="tv.jpg" id="toChange" />

<img src="work.jpg" class="image" data-src="tvWork.jpg" />    // data-attribute is used to store custom data, such as source
<img src="team.jpg" class="image" data-src="tvTeam.jpg" />
<img src="contact.jpg" class="image" data-src="tvContact.jpg" />
```

JavaScript (with JQuery):

```
$(".image").each(function() {
    $(this).hover(function() {    // this is the mouseenter event handler
        $("#toChange").attr("src", $(this).attr("data-src"));
    }, function() {               // this is the mouseleave event handler
        $("#toChange").attr("src", "tv.jpg");    // this will revert it back to the original image (tv.jpg)
    });
});
```

This just changes the `src` attribute of the first `<img>` to a different one on `mouseenter`, and reverts it back on `mouseleave`. (This can be done with regular JS, but JQuery is easier. You can use the same logic).

*Note*: This code is untested. Please comment if I have errors.

Also, if you want hyperlinks, just add them around the image elements. For example:

```
<a href="[hyperlocation_url]"><img src="contact.jpg" class="image" data-src="tvContact.jpg" /></a>
```

See [this](http://jsfiddle.net/012rvmzh/1/) JSFiddle for an example (I tried to replicate yours as best I could --- sorry for the low-res pictures).

Comment: Alright, sorry for not answering, I've been catching up on some school work among other things.  As for your answer..., I think I need to clarify my question.  Rather than having an image change when hovering over it, I need hovering over an image to make another one appear, separate from the one the mouse is over.  I have a menu, with four icons.  Hovering over an icon is supposed to change a TV screen to the left, which displays what the link goes to.  Again, I have my ActionScript example [on my website](http://www.kleinco.org/).  Thanks for your help, still.

Comment: @user3571446 Also just added a JSFiddle link for your viewing pleasure - it works!

Comment: Alright, I'm going to go ahead and try this out now.  I'll let you know if everything goes smoothly (which I assume it will), in which I'll accept the answer.  Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: I attempted this, and despite my best efforts, could not get it to work.  I tried to replicate your test, with no luck.  [Here is the link to the test, you can download the page to see the code used](http://kleinco.org/Banner_Test/).  As far as I can tell, it all checks out.  I created separate .css and .js documents that are tied to this page, as you can see in the code.  Thanks tremendously for your help, though.

Comment: Alright, ignore that, I got things to work.  I forgot about having to download and specifically set the document's javascript to JQuery.  Thanks so much for the time you put into this.

Comment: @user3571446 No problem!